# Default scope in Yii 1.1

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

**AR model Player:**

```
public function scopes()
{
    return array(
        'proleague' => array(
            'condition' => 'mode = "proleague"',
        ),
        'main' => array(
            'condition' => 'mode = "main"',
        ),
    );
}
```

**Using model Player:**

```
Player::model()->
proleague()->
with('startposition')->
findAllByAttributes(... here some condition ...);
```

^^^ That's all ok. Scope-condition will be executed. But...

---

In my project I have many places where any scope for **Player model** doesn't specified and in this cases I need use this **scope-condition as default**:

```
        'main' => array(
            'condition' => 'mode = "main"',
        )
```

If I add **defaultScope()** method to **Player model** like this

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array(
        'condition' => 'mode = "main"',
    );
}
```

the next code

```
Player::model()->
proleague()->
with('startposition')->
findAllByAttributes(... here some condition ...);
```

won't run correct. I won't get **mode = "proleague"** condition, becouse I'll use **defaultScope()** with **mode = "main"**.

---

Any suggestions? How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the [resetScope(true)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#resetScope-detail) method. It "removes" the defaultScope filter.

```
$model = Player::model()->resetScope(true)->proleague();
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new Class for this.

```
<?php   
## e.g. protected/models/
class MyCoreAR extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
        * Switch off the default scope
        */
        private $_defaultScopeDisabled = false; // Flag - whether defaultScope is disabled or not


    public function setDefaultScopeDisabled($bool) 
        {
                $this->_defaultScopeDisabled = $bool;
        }

        public function getDefaultScopeDisabled() 
        {
                return $this->_defaultScopeDisabled;
        }

        public function noScope()
        {
        $obj = clone $this;               
        $obj->setDefaultScopeDisabled(true);

        return $obj;
        }

    // see http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/462/yii-for-beginners-2/#hh16
    public function resetScope($bool = true)
    {
        $this->setDefaultScopeDisabled(true);
        return parent::resetScope($bool);
    }


    public function defaultScope()
    {
        if(!$this->getDefaultScopeDisabled()) {
         return array(
                 'condition' => 'mode = "main"',
            );
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
}
```

In your code:

```
// no default scope
$model = Player::model()->noScope()->proleague();

// with default scope
$model = Player::model()->proleague();
```

Comment: Henry, thank you! Does exists simply way using framework capabilities?